# Does C send method free buffer?

Tags: c, free, send

I have a question about the send method of C.

```
int send (int socket, void *buffer, size_t size, int flags);
```

My code:

```
char *buffer = (char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
send(s, buffer, 100*sizeof(char), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
```

Now I was wondering if I should free the buffer myself or does the send method free it?

My code where I free the buffer:

```
char *buffer = (char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
send(s, buffer, 100*sizeof(char), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
free(buffer);
```

When I saw the error I thought I freed the buffer to soon and the send method was still using the memory.

Let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`send` does not free the buffer.  You need to free it.  Aside from the fact that it simply wasn't designed that way (socket functions are independent of heap functions), send would not actually "know" if the memory should be freed since it could be a pointer to the middle of an allocated chunk of memory or it could be a pointer to stack data.

It should be "safe" to immediately free the buffer after the send call because the function will have copied the data to its own internal buffers.  The code you show would not cause a corruption problem (although I suspect there is more code involved since the buffer is not initialized as shown).  It is possible for the heap to be corrupted earlier in the process and not cause an exception until later (e.g., the free after the send).

The return value of `send` indicates the number of bytes successfully sent (although not necessarily successfully delivered). So while it would be "safe" to free it, you would lose the unsent data if it wasn't all sent.  If the entire buffer was not sent, you would need to call send again with the remaining amount.

Comment: @Tim: Yes, it would be safe to free it right after the send, although you may want to check the return value of send. It indicates the number of bytes successfully sent.

Comment: I see but what if all bytes where successfully send and what if some bytes are not?

Answer (score 1):

You can `free` the buffer after the `send` call returns, noting the following:

- The entire buffer may not have been sent.
- The call returns the number of bytes the kernel has copied into its own buffers. The rest you should keep.

This code may help you understand what is going on, but by no means should you base your own on this:

```
char *buf; // sizeof(*buf) must be 1 for pointer arithmetic
ssize_t sent = send(fd, buf, len, 0);
if (sent != -1) { // no error
    // move the unsent bytes to the start of the buffer
    memmove(buf, buf + sent, len - sent);
    // resize the buffer to fit the left over bytes
    buf = realloc(buf, len - sent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

send() does not free the buffer. If you have double free problems you should look probably look where you free it and check how you get there.

Answer (score 0):

in general, it would be very unordinary if an api function would free a buffer. the only function I know which frees a buffer is "free" ...

sometimes, functions allocate memory you have to free after using them, e.g. strdup

there are some functions, where you can't free the buffer directly after using them. for example, in .Net, you can't dispose the data pointer of a bitmap if it is still used in a bitmap wrapper.

Comment: realloc() can also release memory allocated from the free store, if passed a size of zero.  Otherwise, you are correct -- only heap API functions such as free() and realloc() can free memory obtained from the free store.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds from your description as if you are suffering from your code making use of a pointer after it has been freed.  There are good, solid ways of catching this type of problem, and then there are quick hacks.  Here is a quick hack:

```
#define free(p) do { (free)(p); p=(void*)1; } while (0)
```

This macro, which you would want to include in your header file or the first line of your project, replaces your calls to free so that:

1. The memory is still `free()`'d, the notation `(free)(p)` forces the C compiler to evaluate `(free)` as a function symbol, not a macro expansion.
2. The pointer is set to an inaccessible value, 1.  The value `NULL` (0) wasn't used because `free()` won't complain if passed `NULL`.  Passing a "pointer value" of 1 should trigger an error report.

You may find that after using this macro, your code has been derefencing a stale pointer.  Once you have `free`'d memory, the pointers to it will point to the same memory and temporarily will point to the same values in memory -- until a second use of that memory wipes those values out.  Because of this, your program may be able to function for a few lines using stale pointers.  Changing every pointer to `1` when it becomes stale will catch this right away.